# Use of malloc in Pthreads

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, sizeof

This is actual C code from Pthreads:

```
ThreadParms *parms = NULL; 
if ((parms = (ThreadParms *) malloc (sizeof (*parms))) == NULL)
    {
      goto FAIL0;
    }

  parms->tid = thread;
  parms->start = start;
  parms->arg = arg;
```

Why did they choose to malloc *parms instead of ThreadParms?  It looks like it is allocating only a pointer (which would be an error), but it apparently allocating the size of the whole structure.  Is this correct?

Comment: `sizeof` can take a type or a variable

Comment: I guess my take on it is since they decided to cast the malloc, why not just have ThreadParms in the sizeof()?  That said, I will confess the syntax of sizeof(* something) threw me a bit.  That is my shortcoming.

Comment: `*params` dereferences to a `ThreadParams` type, so you'll `malloc` the full size of the structure with either method. As the answers say this saves on maintenance costs should the `params` type ever change.

Comment: `sizeof *params` is the same as `sizeof (ThreadParms)`, as `*parms` dereferences the pointer, getting to the full type `ThreadParms`.  What actually would be an error is to `malloc(sizeof(parms));` which is actually the pointer value, without any derreference, and should alloc the size of a pointer.

Comment: So in the code, the parens around *parms for the sizeof are extraneous, and perhaps, even improper (though it still works fine).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a common trick in C - using dereference pointer expression in place of the actual type.

The rationale is as follows: if you have

```
some_type *some_var = malloc(sizeof(*some_var));
```

and then change `some_type` to `some_other_type`, the code would continue working fine with only one change.

However, if you start with

```
some_type *some_var = malloc(sizeof(some_type));
```

then you have to change `some_type` in two places:

```
some_other_type *some_var = malloc(sizeof(some_other_type));
```

or your code would have an error.

> It looks like it is allocating only a pointer (which would be an error)

The asterisk makes `sizeof` evaluate to the size of the entire `struct`, so the code is correct.

Comment: I see that.  But they didn't quite do that, did they?  Because of the (unneeded) casting of the malloc? LOL.  (I'm thinking they casted it to make the code C++ compliant, but I am not sure.)

Comment: @Jiminion I'm pretty sure it's for C++, too.

Comment: It's from a .c file.  (create.c).  Maybe it is habit.  (And I don't want to get into the cast or don't cast malloc() debate.... ) :)

Comment: @Jiminion, nope, that notation is valid in C++ without a cast, as `malloc(3)` in c++ has the same prototype as in C, returning a `void *`, which is compatible with any other pointer.  Indeed, malloc **is not a C++ function**.  In C++ you must use `new` and `delete` operators, and never `malloc(3)` (which is not an operator, but a library function)  If `malloc(3)` is allowed in C++ is because it (C++) is source code compatible with C, allowing you to use the majority of C functions without having to write a C++ binding for them.

Answer (score 3):

`*parms` is of `ThreadParms` type so size is OK

It's sometimes seen as better to do like this than the old `sizeof(ThreadParms)`, so if type of `parms` changes the size follows (the assignment and the `sizeof` statement are on the same line)

(however that's not perfect and does not protect against a copy/paste error when allocating some other type with the same line, but it's generally better)

Comment: Right.  But you'd still have to change the casting of the malloc in this case, no?

Comment: no need to cast because malloc returns void* (generic pointer). I'm saying that but I learned that only a few days ago and had to make a compile test to make sure :)

Answer (score 3):

> Why did they choose to malloc *parms instead of ThreadParms.

It's a common practice to use so in case if the type of `parms` changes in the future, then maintenance is easier. But using `ThreadParms` would work just as well.

> It looks like it is allocating only a pointer (which would be an
>   error), but it apparently allocating the size of the whole structure.
>   Is this correct?

No. It's actually equivalent to using `sizeof(ThreadParms)` as the sizeof operator only needs the type information and it doesn't evaluate its operand (except C99 [Variable Length Arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)). The type of `*parms` is `ThreadParms` and that's all `sizeof` needs to know.

Side note: the cast to `ThreadParms *` is unnecessary in C as `void *` can be assigned any other data pointer.

Comment: wouldn't sizeof(char *) evaluate to a pointer?  (Not a char?)

Comment: Yes. But that's not the case here. `sizeof` only needs to the *type* of `*parms` which is `ThreadParms`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes, just clarifying the 'evaluation of operand' point.

Comment: @Jiminion, yes, but that's a type definition, not an expression.  `Sizeof` is an operator in C, and it requires parenthesis when you use a type, and does not when you are using an lvalue.  You can try `sizeof *parms` and it compiles ok, but `sizeof ThreadParms` will tell you that you need to put parenthesis around a type name. Indeed, you can assume you need an expressión, and consider that enclosing a type in parenthesis forms a cast of the null expression to the proper type.